# MVC3 with EF 4.1 and EntityState.Modified on update

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm having problems understanding EntityState.Modified when it comes to updating an object with .NET MVC3.

I have a model that stores an ImageFilePath and ImageContentType when an image is uploaded. Here is what the create action looks like.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SneakPeekCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        try
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                var filepath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../../Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                image.SaveAs(filepath);
                collection.ImageContentType = image.ContentType;
                collection.ImageFilePath = "~/Uploads/" + image.FileName;

            }
            _db.SneakPeekCollections.Add(collection);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The problem comes when trying to edit and subsequently update this object. This is my Edit action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, SneakPeekCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        try
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                var filepath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../../../Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                image.SaveAs(filepath);
                collection.ImageContentType = image.ContentType;
                collection.ImageFilePath = "~/Uploads/" + image.FileName;
            }
            _db.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I believe the problem comes from the fact that I'm setting EntityState.Modified which marks all properties as modified. If I don't upload a new image, the ImageFilePath and ImageContentType coming from the front-end are effectively null which is what is getting stored.

My question is how do I resolve this? What is the proper way to use EntityState.Modified?

Comment: Is your problem solved? What solution did you use? Please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using implicit model binding by accepting a SneakPeakCollection in your parameters, you could retrieve the model from the db and use UpdateModel to get the new values if they exist. Something like this:

```
var collection = _db.SneakPeaks.Find(id); // Get the entity to update from the db
UpdateModel(collection); // Explicitly invoke model binding
if (image != null)
{
                var filepath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../../../Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                image.SaveAs(filepath);
                collection.ImageContentType = image.ContentType;
                collection.ImageFilePath = "~/Uploads/" + image.FileName;
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your submit you need to check whether model is valid, and then run your CRUD routines.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
   // Save my model
}
```

Comment: This has no effect. The object saves just fine but like I mentioned it clears the ImageFilePath and ImageContentType properties because they are not explicitly set and EntityState.Modified has been called.

Comment: Can you please post your SneakPeak class definition?

Answer (score 0):

The complete info you can find here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Comment: Hey Peretz. Thank you. I read your link and was able to solve my problem where I need to maintain CreatedOn value in Edit form post. What I did is, in Edit Post i fetched existing row and from that data I got CreratedOn value and set it for Model Object in post... is it right? what you say?